# Объясните почему нужно использовать именно цифру 10 в этом уравнении

Tags: python, float

Условие

Дано положительное действительное число X. Выведите его первую цифру после десятичной точки.

Решение

```
x = float(input())
print(int(x * 10) % 10)
```

Объясните почему нужно использовать именно цифру 10 в уравнении, откуда мы ее взяли, заранее спасибо. Можно ли еще каким то другим образом решить эту задачу?

Comment: Перевести в строку

Comment: Строго говоря, это вообще не уравнение. Это формула.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мы используем десятичную систему счисления.

Умножение на десятку переводит первую после точки цифру в разряд единиц.

```
123.4 * 10 = 1234
```

Взятие остатка от деления по модулю 10 оставляет от числа только разряд единиц.

```
1234 % 10 = 4
```

В итоге Вы находите то, что искали.

Решить можно многими способами, но этот, навскидку, самый логичный.

Comment: вы упустили важную деталь `int` - `int(123.456 * 10)`

Comment: @S.Nick в моем ответе речь про числа в отрыве от программирования. Насколько я понимаю, в примере автора к `int` приводится только для возможности взять остаток.

Answer (score 2):

Оттуда, что у нас используется десятичная система записи чисел. Проделайте вычисления на бумажке и все станет ясно.

Можно решить и другим способом, да. И даже не одним.